# Given an input string how do i convert character into B

Tags: c

Given an input string how do I convert a character lets say the letter "**a**" into .

For example if input string is "**ash**" after conversion the new string is " **sh**".

In C.

Comment: In C a string is just an array of characters. You can loop over the length of the string and if a character equals the one you want to replace, set the character in that space to what you want to.

Comment: `if(str[index] == 'a') str[index] = ' ';`

Comment: Instead of using `strsep` you could repetitively use `strchr` to look for `'a'` and simply overwrite it with, errm, "whitespace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `char *` pointer to achieve this:

```
void myfunction(char *str) {
    for (; *str != '\0'; str++) {
        if (*str == 'a') {
            *str = ' ';
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf[] = "ash";

    myfunction(buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why strsep ?

You just loop on the string characters and change the char in place with a simple if.